# I can't get around INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables in my database. One of which is a table called `players` and the other one is `bans`:

```
players table: ID, Score
bans table: user_id, reason
```

What I need to do is: select players that where **reason = cheating** and **Score < 250**.

I tried doing some JOINS when I tried FULL JOIN I found that thing doesn't exist in MySQL so any help would be good, thanks in advance!

I also tried it like this but I always get zero rows

```
SELECT bans.user_id, players.ID
FROM bans
INNER JOIN players ON bans.user_id=players.ID;
```

BANS TABLE

```
user_id      reason
133032       swearing
133040       name not allowed
```

PLAYERS TABLE

```
id            score
15            13378
21            215216
133032        15
133040        157
```

Comment: This query should give you results, unless there is no player which is banned. Please show us sample data, as tabular text, and the result that you would expect.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edir your question

Comment: There u go I edited

Comment: Your attempt should work at finding rows. You've also not made any attempt to add the criteria *reason* and *score* that you described.

Comment: What are the datatypes for each of the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is a good start. For your sample data, it will give you results. To meet your requirement, you just need a few additional filters:

```
select b.user_id, p.id
from bans b
inner join players p 
    on  p.id = b.user_id
    and p.score < 250
where b.reason = 'cheating'
```

Comment: For some reason when I run that query I get the next error
`MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'bans.user_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @omcho: sorry that's my mistake, I added table aliases to your tables but did not use them in the `select` clause. Fixed now.